# Getting data from a remote sql server - iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios

I am looking for a way to get data from a sql server, for iPhone. I have done research and found that this can accompished using PHP, but I am not very familiar with PHP, so is there any wrapper or library which would let me directly get data from sql server?

thank you,

Tushar Chutani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked a few times here.

Check out this potentially very related question:

[What is the best way of connecting to a remote server/database to retrieve data from the IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373011/what-is-the-best-way-of-connecting-to-a-remote-server-database-to-retrieve-data)